# Hiding element after css transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, reflow

I have this element that starts hidden and then gets animated with a css transition on a click event.
I know the `display` property cannot be animated, so what I do is remove the class that applies the `display:none`, and then make the change that triggers the css transition, like so:

```
    popin.classList.remove('hidden') // removes the display:none property
    setTimeout(() => {
        popin.classList.remove('closed') // triggers transition
    }, 10)
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wre2674p/6/ for a full example.

I've found out that in order to work, the 2nd step must be done asynchronously. Put it in a `setTimeout` and it works...sort of. In Chrome, any timeout duration works (even 0).
For Firefox and Edge, the behavior varies. For 100ms, it works every time. But for a timeout of e.g. 10ms, the transition works only maybe 50% of times. Since it delays the animation, I wish to keep it as low as possible, while ensuring it works consistently.

I suspect it is related to reflow/repaint occurring when changing `display` property from `none` to `block`, but I lack details on these subjects to full understand what's happening and how to prevent it. Any idea?

Comment: Remove the hidden class from css, remove timeout from js. There is no need to display none the popin since you already have overflow hidden. The transition can be triggered directly, you are over complicating things

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hidden class from CSS and HTML, remove timeout from js. There is no need to display none the `#popin` since you already have overflow hidden. The transition can be triggered directly, you are over complicating things

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function(e){
 let source = e.currentTarget
  source.disabled = true
 let popin = document.getElementById('popin')
  
  if (popin.classList.contains('closed')){
      popin.classList.remove('closed')
  }
  else{
      popin.classList.add('closed')
  }
  
  setTimeout(() => {
   source.disabled = false
  }, 850)
})
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

#popin{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  /*transform: translate(0, 0);*/
  transition: opacity 800ms;
  opacity: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#popin.closed{
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>

<div id="popin" class="closed">
  <h1>Popin</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The transition in the fiddle is just an example. This is a kind of template generator, and any transition can be made. For a fade-in/fade-out for instance the display none is necessary. I updated the fiddle to use that example instead.

Comment: @Antoine answer edited but same idea, you don't need display none, simply add `z-index; -1` to the invisible element

Comment: z-index does not apply to child elements. And even when applying it, it does not really hides the elements. For instance, links are still clickable. See http://jsfiddle.net/wre2674p/9/: when you hover where the link should be, the cursor changes to pointer, the link destination is visible and you can click the link when it's hidden. So this is not a solution.

Comment: @Antoine this is due to the fact that there is no content on the page at all, see http://jsfiddle.net/wre2674p/11/ unless you won't have any content on your page at all except for the popin itself then this is not an issue. you only need z-index -1 on the popin element, children follows

Comment: Sure, but I have no control over what the content of the page will be. Out of the hundreds or thousands of expected uses of this code, Murphy's law  says it will be an issue at some point.

Comment: All pages will have some content and the z-index method is working as it should.

Comment: Having content is not enough; it needs to completely cover the clickable element. There is no guarantee that every clickable zone in the popin (which can be a very large portion of the viewport) will have an element in front it to cover it completely.

Comment: If your page won't have content to fill a normal viewport then it would look weird because half of the page would be empty space that is outside of `body`. Also your popin will most likely be position fixed and not absolute. If you don't want to use this method then you will have to listen(using js) to the end of the transition on popin then add class to hide the element. that's extra code that could be saved, I haven't seen a site that can't even fill a normal viewport with content. By content I mean any div or whatever

Comment: I have also edited the answer to include `pointer-events: none;` so nothing will be visible to the user even if your page has nothing on it. You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/wre2674p/12/